# Why does my default sound output change when I reboot?

Tags: 11.04, sound, xbmc

I have a media center computer that was working fine. I changed something and now have an odd problem.

In my sound preferences, I have 2 output devices, "Internal Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)" and "Internal Audio". Since I have my TV plugged into the HDMI port, when the HDMI option is selected, everything works great. When the other option is selected, it does not.

Logging in and out doesn't change this setting. A reboot does.

Put another way:

1. Log in as regular user, ubuntu session
2. Set the output to the "...(HDMI)"
3. Sound works
4. Log out
5. Log in as regular user, XBMC session
6. Setting stays set, sound works.

However:

1. Log in as regular user
2. Set the sound output to "...(HDMI)"
3. Sound works
4. Reboot
5. Log in as regular user, any session type
6. No sound, sound output is back to "Internal Audio"

So I suspect there is a 'default' somewhere that I'm missing. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Somewhat less important now as I've upgraded to 11.10 and this appears to have gone away. HDMI sound is the only one available now so it's working fine.

Comment: with 22.04 it is back

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by the OP with an upgrade.

> I've upgraded to 11.10 and this appears to have gone away.